# Putting .exe file in windows autorun with python

Tags: python, windows

I'm writing installer for my program with python.
When everything is extracted, how can i make my program .exe file to run with Windows startup?
I want to make it fully automatic, without any user input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Python for this. You can copy your .exe file and paste it in this directory:

> C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
> Menu\Programs\Startup

It will run automatically when your computer starts.

Comment: But how can i make that program will know user name ?

Comment: In the answer by H. pap it is already written how to do it, so it’s not important anymore